# How to create a response form using html, css, jquery, and php that begins minimized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this container that I would like to be able to minimize and maximize.

```
<section class="box-position">
  <div class="containerfoo">
    <div class="  col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-4 pull-right">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Message box title  -->
        <div class="panel-heading top-bar ">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
            <p class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Message</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus icon_minim"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Message body   -->
        <div class="panel-body msg_container_base info">
          <form class="contact-form" action="contact-form.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="input-group">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When my page loads up, I want the item to start minimized. To do this, I gave the container the css style `.containerfoo .info {display: none}`. That works great, to be able to maximize and minimize from there I used javascript:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.icon_minim', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapse')) {
      $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
      $this.removeClass('panel-collapse');
      $this.removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    } else {
      $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
      $this.addClass('panel-collapse');
      $this.removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    }
  });
</script>
```

This javascript makes me able to maximize the text box, but from there I cannot minimize it again... what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is backwards, you say if it does NOT have `panel-collapse` then `removeClass('panel-collapse')`, and else add it. So it will never add it back.  Should be:

```
if ($this.hasClass('panel-collapse')) {
  $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
  $this.removeClass('panel-collapse');
  $this.removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
} else {
  $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
  $this.addClass('panel-collapse');
  $this.removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
}
```

You may also have to flip the glyphicon plus/minus statements, I didn't look into that far, but it should be readily obvious after making this change.